# Debezium kafka connect connector not updating successfully

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to CDC using Debezium and Kafka. I have registered a connector with 3 tables in `table.whitelist` property and it is working properly. Here is the configuration of running connector.

```
{"name":"xoom-eds-extactor","config":{"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector","database.user":"debezium","database.server.id":"1","database.hostname":"qa514dtc001.ord.qa001.xoom.com","database.password":"xoom123","database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"eds-kafka1:9092","database.history.kafka.topic":"dbhistory.inventory","name":"xoom-eds-extactor","database.server.name":"MySQL-Database-Docker","database.port":"3306","include.schema.changes":"true","table.whitelist":"xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.postal_code_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.account_number_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.credit_card_number_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.ip_address_details_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.university_details_mock"},"tasks":[{"connector":"xoom-eds-extactor","task":0}],"type":"source"}
```

Now I want to update the connector and add two more tables from the same database. I am using the following command and config file to update the connector.

**Command** :

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @xoom-eds-extactor-conf.json "http://eds-kafka1:8083/connectors/xoom-eds-extactor/config"
```

**Config json** :

```
{
   "name":"xoom-eds-extactor",
   "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
   "database.hostname":"qa514dtc001.ord.qa001.xoom.com",
   "database.port":"3306",
   "database.user":"debezium",
   "database.password":"xoom123",
   "database.server.id":"1",
   "database.server.name":"MySQL-Database-Docker",
   "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"eds-kafka1:9092",
   "database.history.kafka.topic":"dbhistory.inventory",
   "include.schema.changes":"true",
"table.whitelist":"xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.postal_code_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.account_number_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.credit_card_number_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.ip_address_details_mock,xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.university_details_mock"
}
```

This executes successfully but when I list the Kafka topics only the last 3 topics are present 2 new topics are not added.

```
MySQL-Database-Docker
MySQL-Database-Docker.xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.account_number_mock
MySQL-Database-Docker.xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.credit_card_number_mock
MySQL-Database-Docker.xoom_eds_extraction_src_db_mock.postal_code_mock
__consumer_offsets
connect-configs
connect-offsets
connect-status
dbhistory.inventory
```

Can anyone out there help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Aman! What's the version of Debezium you are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there was an old pending PR related to this issue and it should have been fixed in `0.9.1` release. But if you are using some old version you can simply follow these steps.

- Add the new tables, but don't write to them yet
- Shut down the connector
- Change the filter configuration and set snapshot mode to "**schema_only_recovery**"
- Delete (or rename) the existing DB history topic
- Restart the connector; this will re-create the internal history of the DB schema and then continue streaming from the previously recorded offset
- Begin writing to the new tables

At least this is what we do(we are still using `0.8.2`).

Source : [debezium-google-group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/debezium/Iw4BgLZ8Mq4).